# What does the barkeeper say to James Bond (possibly in Turkish)?

Tags: dialogue, james-bond, skyfall

In the movie Skyfall, the enjoying death scene:
What is the barkeeper saying to James Bond at the next morning at the bar when he is handing the money and grabbing the bottle?

It sounds to me like "furundi" or something, but I could not get a translation. What language is it, and what does it mean?

Comment: @Walt Are you sure that title change is valid at all, given that this has never been part of the question's intent and is only based on information deduced from an answer?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Sorry, thought it might attract the attention of actual Turkish speakers that way (but with a tentative 'possibly'). If it seems invalid, change it back.

Comment: @Walt Nevermind, I forgot that it wasn't just filmed but also set in Turkey, so it's indeed a likely possibility even without seeing the answer.

Comment: Hi. I'm a Turkish member. If you can state the exact time of that scene, I can provide you with the translation.

Comment: @MehperC.Palavuzlar I think it's somewhere in minute 23, in the morning after the scene with the scorpion.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As a native Turkish speaker, let me answer your question.

The bartender says (in Turkish)

**- Sorun değil**

which means

**- No problem.**